# How to make sure that OpenJ9 uses bundled OpenSSL crypto library for ALL crypto operations?

Tags: openssl, openj9

I have built OpenJ9 with my customized OpenSSL, using `--with-openssl` and `--enable-openssl-bundling` options. I can even see `libcrypto.so` in the built binaries, but I'm sure they are not used when I create RSA key pair using `java.security.KeyPairGenerator`. How can I "force" JVM to use OpenSSL for all crypto operations? I've tried `-Djdk.nativeCrypto=true` That didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenJ9 uses openssl for a few select functions, like Digest, CBC, GCM, RSA, and ChaCha20. It may not be used for key generation as that is a less frequently performed operation.

You could try using `-Djdk.nativeCryptoTrace=true` to verify that the native acceleration is being used.